# Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpResponse', but still running OK, How can it be?

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

As you can see here:

https://image.ibb.co/fOzYhA/Cannot-resolve-symbol-but-OK-when-running.jpg

I'm getting an arror:

"Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpResponse' "

and the symbol 'HttpResponse' is displaying in red color, but the code is still running OK and the watch also shows me the value of the variable that I declared from this type.

How can it be? if the Android Studio cannot find a symbol, then how can it still run and show me a valid value for this type?

Please explain,
Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse have smart compiler that can ignore some errors and still run application.

Comment: But it's Android Studio not Eclipse, and I still don't understand how can it show a valid value for a variable of a type that he doesn't recognize, it's not makes sense.